# how to store huge amount of small images

Tags: image-processing, filesystems, storage

I recently have encountered this problem: The program have created large amount of small images, about `2kb` for each. I have directly saved them into the `Ubuntu`'s `ext4` filesystem. But when I explore these images in one of the folders, the images show very slowly. Is there another solutions for this problem? Could you give me some advice, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge number of images in your folder you could try dividing them into subfolders.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Really a simple solution!